# Higher Order Functions in VBA, the dirty way

Tags: functional-programming, vba, higher-order-functions

I have been building a small library of VBA functions.  I have a small section with higher order functions that I'd like to share.  It uses strings as delegates/function pointers and `Application.Run` to actually call the functions.

This isn't by any means a true implementation; just a quick and dirty implementation without connecting external libraries or creating objects for every function.  I haven't found real drawbacks yet. `Application.Run` always passes arguments by value, which would be a draw back, but is desirable in all of these implementations.  Also not being able to declare lambdas is a buzz-kill.

```
Public Sub Map(ByVal delegate As String, ByRef sequence As Variant)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(sequence) To UBound(sequence)

        sequence(i) = Application.Run(delegate, sequence(i))

    Next i

End Sub
Public Function Mapped(ByVal delegate As String, ByVal sequence As Variant) As Variant

    Mapped = sequence
    Map delegate, Mapped

End Function
Public Function Fold(ByVal delegate As String, ByVal sequence As Variant, _
                     ByVal initial_value As Variant) As Variant

    Fold = initial_value

    Dim el As Variant
    For Each el In sequence

        Fold = Application.Run(delegate, Fold, el)

    Next el

End Function
Public Function Reduce(ByVal delegate As String, ByVal sequence As Variant) As Variant

    ' Head and Tail return the first element and the rest, respectively.
    Reduce = Fold(delegate, Tail(sequence), Head(sequence))

End Function
Public Function Compose(ByVal delegates As Variant, ByVal initial_value As Variant) As Variant

    Compose = initial_value

    Dim delegate As Variant
    For Each delegate In delegates

        Compose = Application.Run(delegate, Compose)

    Next delegate

End Function
```

Comment: When you say "without connecting external libraries" did you mean something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204509/Functors-in-VBA

Comment: Yes.  However that is a far better library than the one's I had [had heard about](http://unlimitedexcel.blogspot.com/2011/12/pointers-in-vba-huhh-delegates-in-vba.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Things I like

- This idea.
- You've explicitly declared `ByVal` and `ByRef`.
- All methods are short, clear, and concise.

### Things to watch out for

- All of these functions take variants in as parameters, by necessity. Client code runs the risk of passing in a `sequence` that isn't enumerable. These really need a comment and maybe a `VB_Description` attribute describing what kind of arguments the functions expect.
- You also may want to consider handling runtime error 438 "Object doesn't support Method" for the functions that use `For Each` loops. There's not much you can do other than return a more meaningful error message though.
- If you change the loop in `Map` to a `For Each` and manually increment `i`, all of the functions will be compatible with collections as well as arrays.

### Nitpicks

- Underscores have a special meaning. They indicate event procedures. So I would change `initial_value` to `initialValue`.
- While I quickly understood that `el` stood for `element`, there's no reason not to just spell it out.

Comment: If the loop in `Map` is changed to a `For Each` and `i` is manually incremented, then one should `declare Option Base 1` since Arrays are zero-indexed by default, while Collections are one-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

you have extra newlines in your for loops, and other blocks of code, like this

> ```
> For Each el In sequence
>
>     Fold = Application.Run(delegate, Fold, el)
>
> Next el
> ```

Remove them

```
For Each el In sequence
    Fold = Application.Run(delegate, Fold, el)
Next el
```

There isn't the need for them.

your functions and subs also look like this,

> ```
> Public Function Mapped(ByVal delegate As String, ByVal sequence As Variant) As Variant
>
>     Mapped = sequence
>     Map delegate, Mapped
>
> End Function
> ```

it looks like you think something needs to be added but you didn't put in any comments to say what you are thinking about...

```
Public Function Mapped(ByVal delegate As String, ByVal sequence As Variant) As Variant
    Mapped = sequence
    Map delegate, Mapped
End Function
```

is what this should look like.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this is just a personal preference?  I did remove blank lines until [I was instructed to do differently](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47591/in-place-quicksort/47624#47624).  To be honest, I rather like using new lines to delineate different logical steps.

Comment: @ptwales, that was all in the same Sub, your subs and functions don't have that much in them that they need to be separated to distinguish between steps.  I would space between the functions and subs though, that makes sense.

Comment: I would definitely class it under personal preference.